# What are the symptoms of over stress?

Tags: stress

What are the symptoms of over stress?

I define "over stress" as the state where the amount of stress hormone has exceeded an optimal threshold for performance, and where the arousal is very high (see the picture below, from the blog "[I Done This](http://blog.idonethis.com/science-stress-management-brain-cortisol/)").

[image]

The documentation (the [article](http://blog.idonethis.com/science-stress-management-brain-cortisol/) from the blog "I Done This", and Lupien (2020)) I was able to read point to symptoms like anxiety, impaired performance, loss of memory, confusion of thoughts.

But I wonder if there are any other symptoms, like irritability, impulsiveness, etc.

This [question and answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/how-to-measure-your-stress-levels?rq=1) tackle only in part my question. The answer focuses on the cognitive appraisal by the experiencer, and the question was framed to target stress as a long-lasting experience (several days), while I am focusing on a stress which lasts for a couple of minutes to a couple of hours.

**References and credits:**

Lupien, S. (2020). *Par amour du stress*. Éditions Va savoir.

http://blog.idonethis.com/science-stress-management-brain-cortisol/

Answer (score 1):

anxiety, impaired performance, loss of memory, and confusion of thoughts, are indeed common indicators of over stress. In addition to those, irritability, impulsiveness, changes in sleep patterns, physical symptoms like headaches or muscle pain, and even digestive problems can also be associated with elevated stress levels. It's important to note that the symptoms can vary from person to person and can be influenced by a range of factors. If you want to understand the biological cause of this put it in comment.

Comment: I would like to understand the biological cause of this. Would it be possible to add some references to the assertion in your answer?

Comment: There was a typo in my previous comment, sorry